# let admin to register new user on frontpage on joomla 3

Tags: joomla, registration

I disabled user registration and I want to let only the admin to register new user. Is that possible?
I tried to add a menu item for registration, the page shows only the current users data, it doesn't let me fill the form to register the new user.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: I think admin can add new user only on back end of the site. Try to find some module for that.

Comment: Thanks, I found a module as you said.